# How does Canonical choose Linux kernel version for Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, canonical

I have Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and the Linux kernel version is 4.13.0-39. But in [The Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org) I can't find version 4.13.

Edit 1:
How do they choose what Linux kernel version to put in the next point release of LTS version with LTS Enablement Stack?

Edit 2:
What are the criterias to pick a Linux kernel version and put in a Ubuntu version?

LTS enablement stack bring new Linux kernel version along with a point release, but wouldn't that bring the "bugs" from the recently released version?

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Ubuntu systems run with the Ubuntu kernels provided by the Ubuntu repositories. However it is handy to be able to test with
>   unmodified upstream kernels to help locate problems in the Ubuntu
>   kernel patches, or to confirm that upstream has fixed a specific
>   issue. To this end we now offer select upstream kernel builds. These
>   kernels are made from unmodified kernel source but using the Ubuntu
>   kernel configuration files. These are then packaged as Ubuntu .deb
>   files for simple installation.
>
> ```
> These kernels are not supported and are not appropriate for production use.
> ```

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds and http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D for more details.